# How to calculate a weighted average?

Tags: microsoft-excel

In a pivot table:

```
hits viewTime
2    100
3    300
4    540
5    10
```

I would like to calculate the weighted average of the `viewTime`. I can "just" through out a formula, but I'd like it to work even if the data is changed (new hits add etc).

Please advice about the proper way do make it happen.

**Update**: to clarify, under "weighted average" I mean something like:

```
(100*2+300*3+540*4+10*5)/(2+3+4+5)
```

Comment: you could try `sumproduct()` - by default excel updates cells that reference other cells that are changed; do you have the data in a pivot table and want the result also in the pivot table? Or is the data in some cells and you want a pivot table to show the results?

Comment: Add the cells to do the computations.

Comment: @Raystafarian the data is in the pivot table and I don't really care where the output should be, it's something like `=sumproduct(...)/sum(...)` but I'd like the result to be updated when the pivot data refreshes

Comment: @BreakPhreak Is your pivot table a simple one like in your question or is it more complex? Could you even have a screenshot of your pivot table?

Comment: @Jerry let's assume it is simple like the one above

Comment: @BreakPhreak Just in case that's not what you're looking for, here's how my suggestion looks like: http://i.stack.imgur.com/DOwWs.png The first average doesn't need update, while the second does (I used it only as a check to ensure that the first average is working as intended). It depends on the 'Grand Total' though, so that's why I asked whether it was simple or not. Let me know if that suits you and will put it as answer if yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data range or pivot table is in columns A and B, then you can use:

```
=sumproduct(A:A,B:B)/sum(A:A)
```

This works if you have a pivot table with a grand total of the ViewTime as well.